# Running games through RemoteApp

Tags: remote-desktop, gaming, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to build a solution which allows me to keep my games and production software separated, without having to dual-boot and while keeping the ability to use *Hyper-V* on the host (since it's used to develop *UWP* apps and I need the emulators).

I decided to try the *RemoteApp* feature by installing Windows Server 2012 R2 on a newly created *Hyper-V* machine and, using [RemoteApp Tool](http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool), I did a test with an old copy of *Age of Empires 3*.

What I get is a message saying:

> The game cannot be run in a remote desktop session

which stops me from playing.

I've also tried by manually configuring the server with *RD* roles and stuff, but it fails the connection because of certificate issues (I wasn't able to use a self-signed certificate for some reasons).

Since I'm finding online posts telling that it's possible to play through *RemoteApp*, is there any kind of solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Another job for MS!

All jokes aside, don't use RD or RA for that. Use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en-us/download/windows/). It's free and it allows you to run games, as you're connecting to the console rather than a RD socket.

Comment: Well, the vm is in the same newtork as the host (same pc too), connecting through another server looks like a huge overkill and a loss of performance. Plus, the "cool thing" was to be able to double-click and launch the program (using a `.rdp` file for each *RemoteApp* that I wanted to expose) :)

Comment: @StepTNT yes... well, this is the only way to do it. only OpenGL will launch in RDP, not DX based games

Comment: While correct that DX is not supported over RDP, the reason why the game is not starting is that it has an internal check for the RDP session (due to probably licensing concerns). You can work around that by logging in physically to the target machine, starting the game and then starting an RD session with the same user.

Comment: Oh well, given that we're talking about a VM it will be a bit hard. I'll try if I can use *TeamViewer* just to launch the game before switching to *RDP*, even if I'll lose the "double-click-to-launch" feature.